# Zend DB multiple joins don't work

Tags: php, zend-db

I have the following code, this way it does not work.

```
    $query = $this->select()
    ->from(array('c' => 'contrato'),
            array('*'))
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->join(array('ch'   => 'contrato_host'),'ch.id_host         = '.$id_host.' and ch.id_contrato = c.id_contrato', array())
            ->joinUsing('contrato_tipo', 'id_contrato_tipo', 'ds_contrato_tipo')
            ->joinUsing('fornecedor',   'id_fornecedor', 'razao_social')
    ->where('id_cliente     = ?', $id_cliente)
    ->order(array('id_contrato DESC'));
```

But when I use just it works

`$query = $this->select()
        ->from(array('c' => 'contrato'),
        array('*'))
                <br/>->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                <br/>->join(array('ch'  => 'contrato_host'),'ch.id_host         = '.$id_host.' and ch.id_contrato = c.id_contrato', array())
        <br/>->where('id_cliente    = ?', $id_cliente)
        <br/>->order(array('id_contrato DESC'));`



I don't know why, but when I did the code by hand it works

`SELECT 
contrato.*, contrato_tipo.ds_contrato_tipo, fornecedor.razao_social
  FROM [action].[dbo].[contrato]
  INNER JOIN [action].[dbo].[contrato_host] ON [contrato_host].id_host = 14 and [contrato_host].id_contrato = [contrato].id_contrato
  INNER JOIN [action].[dbo].[contrato_tipo] ON contrato_tipo.id_contrato_tipo = contrato.id_contrato_tipo
  INNER JOIN [action].[dbo].fornecedor ON fornecedor.id_fornecedor = contrato.id_fornecedor
WHERE ([contrato].id_cliente = '1') ORDER BY "id_contrato" DESC`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->select()
->from(array('c'=>'contrato'),
        array('*'))
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->join(array('ch'=>'contrato_host'),'ch.id_host='.$id_host.' and ch.id_contrato = c.id_contrato', array())
        ->join('contrato_tipo','id_contrato_tipo','ds_contrato_tipo',array())
        ->join('fornecedor','id_fornecedor', 'razao_social',array())
->where('id_cliente= ?',$id_cliente)
->order(array('id_contrato DESC'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could format the other codeblocks.
And please also post the value from:

```
echo $query->__toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the "joinUsing" function before, maybe try this instead:

```
$query = $this->select()
              ->from(array('c' => 'contrato'), array('*'))
              ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
              ->join(array('ch' => 'contrato_host'),'ch.id_host = '.$id_host.' and ch.id_contrato = c.id_contrato', array())
              ->join(array('ct' => 'contrato_tipo'), 'ct.id_contrato_tipo = c.id_contrato_tipo', 'ds_contrato_tipo')
              ->join(array('f' => 'fornecedor'), 'f.id_fornecedor = c.id_fornecedor', 'razao_social')
              ->where('c.id_cliente = ?', $id_cliente)
              ->order(array('c.id_contrato DESC'));
```